# How can I propagate a community of anaerobic bacteria sampled from mud in a bog?

Tags: bacteriology, ecology, cell-culture

I'm doing research on anaerobic bacteria. In the fall I took mud samples from a bog and have been working with them but I didn't take enough. Now winter has rolled around (Im in Canada) and all the bogs are frozen over. I need more material to work with — is it possible to make a mud mixture myself and carry over the bacteria?  If so could anyone help me out with the mixture ratios? Is contamination a concern here (I would assume not)? And how long would the propagation take?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. I've made edits to your question that I think make it a better fit for this site — please check to make sure I haven't broken anything! We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, could you use a [Winogradsky column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winogradsky_column)? Thanks! 

Comment: I suggest getting an augur or whatever it used to make ice holes for fishing , and cut  down into the bog and get more samples.